# Differential Equation which I am unable to solve: $(14-6y+e^{-3x})~dx-2~dy=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do I solve this differential equation, I'm struggling...

$$(14-6y+e^{-3x})~dx-2~dy=0$$

It's obviously not an exact equation and it's also not separable and these are the only two I know how to solve so please offer as much help as you can (hints, how to change form, solutions).

Thanks!

Comment: look for solution in the form of $y=ae^{-3x}x+be^{-3x}+c$

Comment: Oh okay, thanks.

Comment: It becomes an exact equation after multiplying both sides by $e^{3x}$.

Answer (score 4):

Notice that your differential equation can be rewritten as:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}+3y=\frac{e^{-3x}}{2}+7 \tag{1}$$
This is a linear non-homogeneous ordinary differential equation, since it is in the form:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}+p(x)y=q(x)$$
There are many ways to solve this, such as [Variation of Parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters#First_order_equation) or using [Laplace Transforms](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/IVPWithLaplace.aspx). I will use the [integrating factor method](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Linear.aspx), which is likely the easiest one in your case. The integrating factor can be proven to be given by $\mu(x)=e^{\int p(x)~dx}$ in general.

---

Therefore, in your case, we have $\mu(x)=e^{\int 3~dx}=e^{3x}$ (The constant of integration can be omitted). We now multiply equation $(1)$ by $\mu(x)$ on both sides.
$$\begin{align}e^{3x}\cdot \frac{dy}{dx}+3e^{3x}\cdot y&=e^{3x}\left(\frac{e^{-3x}}{2}+7\right)\\e^{3x}\cdot y'+(e^{3x})'\cdot y&=\frac{1}{2}+7e^{3x} \end{align}$$
As a consequence to multiplying our ODE with $\mu(x)$, we notice that the LHS is a specific case of the product rule. Hence, we can apply the [product rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule) *in reverse*.
$$(e^{3x}y)'=\frac{1}{2}+7e^{3x}$$
All that remains to do is integrate both sides with respect to $x$, and solve explicitly for $y$.

Answer (score 1):

When given a DE of the form

$$ M(x,y)\,dx+N(xy)\,dy=0 $$

which is not exact another method of searching for an integrating factor is to determine whether or not

$$ \frac{1}{N}\left(\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}\right)\tag{1} $$

is a function of $x$ alone, say $p(x)$, or whether

$$ \frac{1}{M}\left(\frac{\partial N}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial M}{\partial x}\right)\tag{2} $$

is a function of $y$ alone, say $q(y)$.

Whichever of these happens to be the case (if either) then

$$\mu(x)=e^{\int p(x)dx}$$

or

$$\mu(y)= e^{\int q(y)dy}$$

will be an integrating factor.

In this case

$$ \frac{1}{N}\left(\frac{\partial M}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial N}{\partial x}\right)=\frac{1}{-2}(-6-0)=3=p(x) $$

so $\mu(x)=e^{\int 3\,dx}=e^{3x}$ is an integrating factor.

$$ (14e^{3x}-6ye^{3x}+1)dx-2e^{3x}dy=0 $$

1. $\dfrac{\partial M}{\partial y}=-6e^{3x}$
2. $\dfrac{\partial N}{\partial x}=-6e^{3x}$

Thus there is a solution of the form $f(x,y)=c$ where $f(x,y)$ satisfies both

$$ f(x,y)=\int M\,dx= \frac{14}{3}e^{3x}-2ye^{3x}+x+c_1(y)$$

and

$$ f(x,y)=\int N\,dy=-2ye^{3x}+c_2(x)$$

Thus the solution is

$$\frac{14}{3}e^{3x}-2ye^{3x}+x=c$$

which can be solved for $y$ to give

$$ y=\left(\frac{x}{2}+c\right)e^{-3x}+\frac{7}{3} $$